# Show total entries in a visual in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am working on a dashboard that is used to provide the user with wrong values using filter in certain tables. I have displayed everything to their liking so far, but they wish for a display of a number that shows how many entries are in a visual (so basically how many wrong values are in the visual)
I've tried to use `COUNTROWS` but it only provides me with the number of total entries in the entire table, not a single visual.
This is what it should look like:

[image: Image of desired result]

Is there a way to implement this?

Tried using `COUNTROWS` but didn't find a way to filter for visuals

Comment: Hi, What you mean by wrong number ? COUNTROWS is a scalar function. It returns a scalar value. If you want to filter out some unintended values , then use it together with calculate like this: CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table),Filter_Column = Filter Condition) Lastly, Your image does not provide almost no info. Summarize what you need by using fake data and copiable texts. Stay safe!

Comment: I thought the picture was self explanatory but I guess i wasn't specific enough. I wanted to know if there is some way that when a visual shows me 5 rows, I can show a number 5 on top of the visual. If it has 4 rows, it shows the number 4, if 3 it shows 3 and so on. Hope that explains it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! I can tell you some way of doing it:

Let's say you have such a table visual:

[image: Apples]

Put the Duplicate [Given Sales Price ] Column in the same visual, then It will look like this:

[image: FGRS]

The with your visual selected, Go to the visualizations pane, find the 2nd [Given Sales Price] Column, click the down pointing arrow and pick count from the opened list, see picture:

[image: SDEAFEF]

Now check the visual:

[image: DFERF]

Note : To see the  [Total] row on the visual, Ensure that Total value field is switched on, see picture:

[image: DFSF]

Or you can do the same using card visuals and putting it above the table visual, see the image:

[image: Card Visual]